# Bootstrap flex: in one row, one col has full height and the other has verticaly center aligned elements

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Im strugling with bootstrap 4 trying to verticaly align the elements of the right column and have a full height column on the the left col, just to have a background color. I ve seen so many posts about these issues but none about this specific aproach

My HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <div class="content colour-1">
                //Just want a full height background color

              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 ..->class?">
            <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >
                //I just want this small form vertically aligned - center
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this? Can it be done only with bootstrap 4? Notice i'm using Angular, so these are my dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.31",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/localize": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.9",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.1.0", -->NG-BOOTSRAP
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.0", --->BOOTSRAP
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="height: 100vh">
        <div class="col-6 d-flex flex-grow-auto">
            <div class="content colour-1">
                //Just want a full background color

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 flex-row d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
            <input class="form-control">
            <input class="form-control">

        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```